# Tablesorter does not sort "-" symbol

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

tablesorter doesn't work on Subject column, when column contain's "-" such as:

```
Name Subject
Anton    -
Max     "dfdsrv"
Anna    "fdsf"
```

but if I add string with spec symbol, it will work correctly!

```
Name Subject
Anton    -
Max     "<dfdsrv>"//correctly working
Anna    "fdsf"
```

P.S Unforunately we are using old tablesorter version 2.0.5.
How I could resolve this problem? I replaced "-" for empty string but it still not work.Maybe I mistaked somewhere?

```
textExtraction: function(node) {
      if (node.innerHTML.text == "-"){
        return " "; 
      } 
}
```

Comment: where is the data coming from? can it be replaced with an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known issue with the default settings. Tablesorter supports parsers for sorting text, URIs, integers, currency, floats, IP addresses, dates (ISO, long and short formats), time.

To fix your problem you should configure tablesorter to use the `text parser`:

```
$(".tbl").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: { sorter:'text' }
    }
});
```

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration

In more complex scenarios (e.g. reformatting, replacement etc.) a viable approach is also to add a custom parser to tablesorter by using the `$.tablesorter.addParser` method.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of problems.

1. The `textExtraction` function needs to return the html at all times:
2. As @TheZenCoder said, the parser needs to be set to "text"; this is due to the "-" being in the first cell of the column. The parser is being set to "digit" because it thinks the "-" is a negative sign.

Here is the full code (& [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1173/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function (node) {
        var txt = node.innerHTML;
        if (txt == "-") {
            return " ";
        }
        return txt;
    },
    headers : {
        1: { sorter: 'text' }
    }
});
```

* Note: if there are any tabs, spaces or other formatting in the table cell, e.g.

```
<td>
  -
</td>
```

then you'll need to trim the results to get an accurate comparison:

```
var txt = $.trim( node.innerHTML );
if (txt == "-") {
```